# Where in the database does fieldset and field instance info live?

Tags: entities

Background: I'm writing a module that will hopefully make reverse-engineering specs for site audits easier. (If you're interested, you can see [the Topograph module-in-progress](https://github.com/bbinkovitz/topograph) on my Github account.)

Basically it's a bunch of byzantine views that use custom handlers to pull things like serialized data out of the DB to display stuff like nodetype settings to the admin user.

I'm having a lot of trouble finding certain things, though. Fieldset info is a major one, as well as settings like whether the field is required. I'm not finding it in the blob of data pulled from the `{field_config_instance}` table (though I might be overlooking it). Can someone point me to where this info can be retrieved per nodetype/field instance?

Comment: i think field_config_instance for example only has like the `required` setting, if the parent field element options are altered in any way for a bundle (because fields can exist in many bundles) ... so i'm not sure you can rely on looking at 1 SQL table. thats why `field_get_info()` exists.

Comment: That function doesn't seem to exist, and the closest thing I could find, `field_info_field()`, doesn't seem to have fieldset or required info in the return value.

Comment: Does it have to be DB, or can you do it via the API?

Comment: Via the API works fine too.

Comment: `field_info_instance()` should do it, the 'required' setting is under 'settings' in that array. By fieldset info do you mean the stuff field_group provides? If so that's in the field_group table. If you're looking at the db structure in a GUI it's easy to miss the field_group table, it gets buried in amongst the field data/revision tables

Comment: im so tiredd :( im not 100% today

Comment: I found the field_group table, but it appears to be empty (in PHPMyAdmin) despite the fact that I have fieldgroups on several content types.

Answer (score 2):

Whether a field is required or not can vary by content type (ie, the bundle).  I am pretty sure you need to use [`field_info_instances($entity_type, $bundle_name)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instances/7).  You can then use [`field_info_field($field_name)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7) on the results.  Something like:

```
$fields_info = field_info_instances('node', $bundle);

foreach ($fields_info as $field_name => $instance) {
  $field_info = field_info_field($field_name);
}
```

`dpm()` both the `$instance` and `$field_info`.  Everything you need should be in those two variables.  This is a snippet from a dynamic exporter I have.

Comment: I will note as a comment, that I am not positive that the fieldset info is in there.

Comment: Fields don't have any related fieldset info as such, some modules (e.g. field_group) provide them but they're stored separately (in a table and as ctools exportables)

Comment: That makes sense.  I hardly every use groups.

Comment: Neither fieldset nor required info is provided by `field_info_instances()` or `field_info_field()`. Clive, if you can tell me where field_group stores fieldset info, please do. I can't find it.